# Калькулятор заказа

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.

Начал учить js, столкнулся с проблемой. Подскажите, пожалуйста, по коду js.  При клике на btn должно по отмеченным чекбоксам показывать заказ,  но проблема в том, что если выбран 1 чекбокс  и после этого нажат btn  и если отметить второй и попытаться вывести данные и второго чекбокса, то показывает все равно только первый. При этом если менять колл. заказа первого он его  перерасчитывает. ((

http://jsfiddle.net/fetfet/ohwehkb2/14/